# fill data to already defined columns in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

i am trying to Bind DateTable to Datagridview that already have columns designed using Designer in VS. Source for DataTable is sql database. I am trying to do this using following code which adds only blank rows in datagridview. also i update the DataPropertyName property of a DGV column with the name of the column in the DataTable

```
SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(mysql.CON.ConnectionString);
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(col.Name);
    col.DataPropertyName = col.Name;
}
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select id,name,age,notes  from test where id = '" + txtID.Text + "'", CN);
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

please nead help to know why the rows are viewed empty with out data

Comment: could you help me to find the error here

Answer (score 0):

i think your **sda.Fill(dt);** is wrong, because according to reference on SqlDataAdapter you may need fill **DataSet** no **DataTable**. Look and learn more about how to get data from database. Try any tutorials rather than you ask on stackoverflow.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171920.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-CZ/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code a little bit:

```
SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(mysql.CON.ConnectionString);
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select id,name,age,notes  from test where id = '" + txtID.Text + "'", CN);
sda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Columns.Count;i++)
{
dataGridView1.Columns[i].DataPropertyName = SelectionChangeCommitted.Columns[i].ColumnName;
}
```